# Can't re-install Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I tried to re-install Pokemon Go and I keep getting "authentication error. must sign in to Google account."  I'm signed into my Google account.  I am logged into my Pokemon Go account at Pokemon.com.  I had the app installed on my one previously, then it stopped working I kept getting a retry message.  So, I deleted it to start over.  Obviously that did no good, and just made it worse.  I've looked at many of the Q&A on the internet and nothing resolves my issue.  Same with going to Niantic.  Any answers?

Comment: Niantic has [troubleshooting guides](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web) for both Android and iOS.  They have worked for me when I get the retry message.

Comment: What android version you are using on your phone ? ( in case you are using an android phone )

Answer (score 2):

As Jerry commented on the question:

> Niantic has troubleshooting guides for both Android and iOS.

Common checklist:

1. Try cleaning the app data and log in
2. Do clean uninstall (quit app, clear data, uninstall)
3. Reboot phone
4. Reinstall
5. Sometimes it's a server side thing and you have to wait